# Meaning of "jarring sales." Is it negative?

Tags: meaning

> The first harbingers of Christmas arrive in October when **jarring** sales and decorations follow fast on the heels of summer.

Does the word *jarring* here mean *annoying*, or *early/preliminary*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**jarring**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/jarring) (adjective): causing a strong emotional reaction because of *unexpectedness*

> the *jarring* news that major financial institutions were on the verge of collapse.

disagreeable to one's aesthetic or artistic sense

> the final chord of that song is too *jarring* for me.

Comment: could you please specify what do you mean by _unexpectedness_ here if sales and decoration start in October in USA every year?

Comment: @Vladimir - Christmas is at the end of December. We expect to see decorations go up after another major holiday, Thanksgiving, which falls towards the end of November. To see Christmas decorations before Thanksgiving is something that is offensive, as it is pushing the materialistic aspect of Christmas, and we all complain about it, every year. We expect that any time now, they'll have Christmas sales starting in July (actually, they do. They're called, "Christmas in July" sales.)

Comment: @Susan thanks for explanation! I couldn't believe that Christmas sales start way before Christmas :) probably it's more cultural question than linguistic.

Answer (score 0):

Jarring implies "opposite if comfortable". Its negative in the sense its an uncomfortable or disjointed sale process.